# 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'class_indices'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data

Well I have created a model and I am trying to reach its labels and I want to create a label map for this dataset. I have created the data set in the code below

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "training",
    seed = 123,
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "validation",
    seed = 123,
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size)
```

I am trying it like this in Jupyter Notebook

```
train_ds.class_names
```

It should give an output for the class names, but it gives an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [29], line 1
----> 1 train_ds.class_names

AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'class_names'
```

What should I do? I used the same class_names method before in the same code, it was working but now it gives an error like this. Can you help me?

Comment: Which Keras version you are using?

Comment: Please help us to know which dataset you are using? is it tensorflow dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used an array and give it to the labels as class names. This solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple thing -
just store the data into separate variable before adding a cache and prefetch API.
and the use the variable in further processes.

```
data_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        "dataset/Train/",
        shuffle = True,
         image_size=(256,256),
        batch_size=32, 
)

training_data = data_train

data_train = data_train.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 0):

train_ds.classnames should be declared before caching.
After Caching the type of the dataset changes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).